# Regular expressions for finding patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am having a trouble with adjusting regular expression formula to do what I want.

I want to find a pattern:

```
AxxHxxxAxxHxxxbbbbbAxxHxxxAxxHxxx
```

But not:

```
AxxHxxxAxxHxxxAxxHxxxAxxHxxxAxxHxxxAxxHxxxAxxHxxxAxxHxxx
```

If I use:

```
"(A\w{2}H\w{3}){2,4}.+(A\w{2}H\w{3}){2,4}"
```

It will find both. I've tried excluding long stretches of AxxHxxx repeat by:

```
"(?!(A\w{2}H\w{3}){8})(A\w{2}H\w{3}){2,4}.+(A\w{2}H\w{3}){2,4}"
```

But it's actually not working. Do any of you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Since I will be operating rather on the big set of data, I would like to preferably avoid loop hell with splicing strings and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

As there was an interest in another set of examples I will try to explain in more details what I am trying to accomplish.

I want to find in a single string a fragment which will consist of two repetition and a set of  any characters in between, such as:

```
.......A..H...A..H...A..H...............A..H...A..H...A..H.......................
```

where "." is any character and you have two repetetive modules of "A..H...". The only problem is that I do not want to find continues stretch of repetition such as here:

```
.......A..H...A..H...A..H...A..H...A..H...A..H......................
```

Comment: What's the difference between the first and second string?

Comment: What format can bbbbb have. Can it start with A or H?

Comment: Two repetition modules ("AxxHxxx"*2) are interrupted by "bbbbb". I want the regular expression to find string only with a stretch interrupted by a certain number of characters.

Comment: Yes, it can be anything, except of another repetition of "AxxHxxx".

Comment: @MateuszK Can you give another set of examples ? I cant find the rule you used.

Comment: @SujithPS I've added additional explanation to original question. Thanks!

Comment: @SujithPS: Have you looked at my solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce the correct result with your test cases, but it is very ugly.

`/^(?:A.{2}H.{3})+(?:(?!A.{2}H.{3}).)+(?:A.{2}H.{3})+$/`

http://regex101.com/r/sW5vG2

Is this what you want?

The efficiency will be directly proportional to the length of the string.

Edit: Improved solution using PCRE http://regex101.com/r/wX8uK2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much I understood your problem.

For solving your specific problem , You can use something like this , I think so.

```
^(.*)\1((?!\1).)+\1{2}$
```

Check **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bU7wC0)**